# Inscribed graph in Euclidean Space.

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a $K_{p,q}$. Let's inscribe this graph into Euclidean space, and let any edge in graph be a segment with a length equals $1$. Find minimal dimension of space , with this properties.

Obviously $\text{dim}(V) = \min(p,q)+1$, when $q,p > 2$, but how can we strictly prove it.

Comment: How exactly is this obvious $$\text{dim}(V) = \min(p,q)+1?$$

Comment: @Justin I don't know. But it's actually imaginable

Comment: @Justin maybe this is wrong. But actually I guess so.

Comment: I'm not saying I think it's wrong, I'm just not convinced it's obvious.

Comment: @Justin this is obvious and doesn't obvious at same moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a result of Lenz (see [this paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/graphgeometry/dimensions/eht.pdf) by Erdős, Harary, and Tutte):

$$\textrm{dim}(K_{m,n}) = \begin{cases} 
      1 & m=n=1 \\          
      2 & m=1, n>1 \textrm{ or } m>1, n=1 \\
      2 & m=n=2 \\
      3 & m=2, n>2 \textrm{ or } m>2, n=2 \\
      4 & \textrm{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}$$